# Вывести количество строк в файле

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести количество строк, загруженных из файла? Я написал следующий код, но он выводит именно содержимое строк. А мне нужно количество:

```
def file_load():
    with open("proxy.txt") as proxy:
        ips = [row.rstrip() for row in proxy]
    with open("user-agents.txt") as user_agents:
        ua = [row.rstrip() for row in user_agents]
    with open("referers.txt") as referers:
        ref = [row.rstrip() for row in referers]
    print('Loaded: ', ips, 'proxies,', ua, 'user-agents,', ref, 'referers')
```

Answer (score 11):

Чтобы вывести количество строк в файле, не обязательно сами строки сохранять, достаточно просто посчитать сколько раз символ новой строки встречается в тексте:

```
def count_lines(filename, chunk_size=1<<13):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return sum(chunk.count('\n')
                   for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(chunk_size), ''))
```

Файл открывается в текстовом режиме (перевод строки преобразуется в `'\n'` на всех системах), читается блоками по 8K символов в каждом до конца файла и количество `'\n'` в каждом блоке суммируется, чтобы найти общее число строк.

Код предполагает, что все строки, *включая последнюю*, заканчиваются символом новой строки также как `wc -l` утилита ([принято на POSIX, иначе например, подумайте что будет, если вызвать `cat *.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/4279)). Если последний символ не новая строка, последняя строка не считается (руками единицу добавить можно в этом случае).

Имея `count_lines()` функцию, легко получить желаемый вывод:

```
print('Loaded: {nproxies} proxies, {nuser_agents} user-agents, '
      '{nreferrers} referers'.format(
        nproxies=count_lines('proxy.txt'),
        nuser_agents=count_lines('user-agents.txt'),
        nreferrers=count_lines('referers.txt')))
```

Comment: @Igor: в ответе явно сказано: *"читается блоками по 8K символов в каждом"*. В памяти только один блок одновременно присутствует. Другими словами, можно большие файлы свободно таким образом читать, не боясь всю память съесть.

Comment: @Igor: код в ответе работает как для маленьких так и для больших файлов. Нельзя ожидать, что все люди, которые находят в поисковике вопрос: *"Вывести количество строк в файле"* будут иметь маленькие файлы. Если вас интересует производительность, то [код, похожий на используемый в ответе, может работать даже быстрее C++ аналога, сравнимо с `wc -l` вариантом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python#comment11966378_9371238)

Comment: Для огромных файлов которые не влезают в память это действительно лучший вариант из тех что встречал ранее. Да и кроме счетчика строк file.read(chunk_size) можно ведь использовать для других операций, для бинарных файлов тоже скорее всего будет работать.

Comment: Нашел ошибку в данном методе пока писал вариант с регулярными выражениями. Последнего \n может не быть, будет на 1 элемент меньше. В коде нужно будет проверять конец файла и последние символы для правильного расчета.

Comment: @Igor верно, код предполагает что все строки заканчиваются символом новой строки (принято на \*nix). Я обновил ответ, чтобы упомянуть это явно.

Comment: как вариант делать еще одно чтение только конца файла побитово или через seek() и посмотреть есть ли перед концом файла \n. Если нет прибавить +1. Какое смещение минимально взять чтобы точно не захватить лишнего это пока вопрос. В теории просто в последнем элементе последней итерации проверить символ переноса строки. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260273/most-efficient-way-to-search-the-last-x-lines-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: @Igor Нет необходимости два раза файл читать. Достаточно, явный цикл использовать и добавить единицу в конце, если необходимо: `..chunk = "\n" $  for chunk in iter(..): nlines += chunk.count('\n') $ return nlines + (not chunk.endswith('\n'))`

Answer (score 8):

Если проникнуться [дзеном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) пайтона:

```
sum(1 for line in open('file', ‘r’))
```

На мой взгляд это то, что вам нужно, в легко понятном виде.

Answer (score 6):

Используйте [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)

```
print('Loaded: ', len(ips), 'proxies,', len(ua), 'user-agents,', len(ref), 'referers')
```

Comment: Тогда выводится вот такая строка: `('Loaded: ', 274, 'proxies,', 7478, 'user-agents,', 350, 'referers')` А я хочу, чтобы была такая строка: `Loaded: 274 proxies, 7478 user-agents, 350 referers`

Comment: `print('Loaded: {} proxies, {} user-agents, {} referers'.format(len(ips), len(ua), len(ref)))`

Comment: @kmmik спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вывести количество строк с помощью регулярного выражения. Особенность. Если последняя строка не пустая, то выведет количество на 1 элемент меньше.

```
import re
# выведет все строки включая пустые
len(re.findall(r"[\n']+?", open('bash.txt').read()))

# выведет количество без пустых строк
len(re.findall(r"[\n']+", open('bash.txt').read()))
```

На больших файлах ко всему файлу сразу применять не желательно, возможно проверить на пустые строки построчно или прочитав часть файла, потом сложив длину.

пример текстового файла

```
1. sudo pip3 install django-markdown-deux
2. sudo pip3 install django-filter
3. sudo pip3 install sorl-thumbnail
4. sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev
5. sudo pip3 install Pillow
6. sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++-dev
7. sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.40-dev
8. sudo apt-get install imagemagick
9. sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
10. 
11. 
12. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
13. sudo pip3 install Wand
14. 
15. sudo python3 manage.py makemigrations thumbnail
```

Как это работает. В данном случае жадность регулярного выражения отключена.

```
>>> re.findall(r"[\n']+?", open('bash.txt').read())
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
14
```

Жадность включена, из-за жадности регулярных выражений \n\n будут вместе там где ничего нет кроме переноса

```
>>> re.findall(r"[\n']+", open('bash.txt').read())
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n', '\n', '\n\n', '\n']
11
```

Если посчитаем стандартно, то получим включая пустые строки, что пустая строка тоже строка. Этот метод считает всегда количество строк как мы это понимаем.

```
>>> len(open('bash.txt').readlines())
15
```

Причина по которой отличается количество

```
'sudo pip3 install django-markdown-deux\nsudo pip3 install django-filter\nsudo pip3 install sorl-thumbnail\nsudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev\nsudo pip3 install Pillow\nsudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++-dev\nsudo apt-get install libboost-python1.40-dev\nsudo apt-get install imagemagick\nsudo apt-get install graphicsmagick\n\n\nsudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev\nsudo pip3 install Wand\n\nsudo python3 manage.py makemigrations thumbnail'
```

видна здесь, в конце нет переноса строки который считаем.

Вариант исправления количества строк для регулярных выражений, файл придется читать второй раз с конца.

```
from __future__ import with_statement #tell()

with open('bash.txt', "r") as f:
    f.seek (0, 2)
    fsize = f.tell()
    f.seek (max (fsize-68, 0), 0)
    lines = f.readlines()
lines[-1:]
if '\n' in lines[-1:]:
    print("no")
else:
    print("+1")
```

Если символа переноса в последней строке нет, то прибавить плюс 1, в данном случае просто вывод на экран.

Алтернативное решение этой же проблемы чтение файла с начала построчно, далее взять последнюю строку и проверить в ней символ

```
open('bash.txt', "r").readlines()[-1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f=open('proxy.txt')
i=0
for line in f:
    i
    i+=1
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была задача посчитать количество непустых строк в файле. Предлагаю код, который нормально решает задачку со строками в том числе и с последней непустой без прочтения файла с конца:

```
def file_lines_amount(filename: str) -> int:
    import re
    '''
    Calculates the number of non-empty lines in a file.
    '''
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return len(re.findall(r".+\n*", f.read()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    # Update the directory with the script.
    abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
    os.chdir(dname)
    print(file_lines_amount('lines.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Однострочник с вызовом утилиты wc:

```py
>>> int(subprocess.check_output(['wc', '-l', 'text.out']).split()[0])
801
```