# Определить количество строк в строковой переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно посчитать количество строк в строковой переменной?

```
>>> lines_count('test\nstring\n')
2

>>> lines_count('test\nstring')
2

>>> lines_count('test\nstring\n\n')
3

>>> lines_count('')
0

>>> def lines_count(s):
...     return <?>
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вывести количество строк в файле](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550742/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Строковые переменные имеют метод [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), который можно использовать для разбиения на строки. При этом будут правильно обработаны различные способы разбиения на строки и крайние случаи с наличием переноса строки в конце:

```
def lines_count(s):
    return len(s.splitlines())
```

Тем не менее, в этом случае создаётся временный список, который может быть довольно большим.

---

Если использовать метод [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), то нужно проверять наличие переноса строки на конце:

```
def lines_count(s):
    if not s:
        return 0

    count = s.count('\n')
    if not s.endswith('\n'):
        count += 1
    return count
```

Здесь распознаются только символы `\n`, но не создаётся список.
К сожалению, добавить распознавание всех случаев из `splitlines` довольно трудоёмко.

---

Насколько я понимаю, в стандартной библиотеке Python нет функции, объединяющей достоинства обоих методов.

Comment: Все утро читал ваш пост. Если вам нужно разделять строковую переменную(на подстроки) типа str по символу '\n', то у вас же все решено. Кол-во '\n' и будет кол-м подстрок. Если разделитель будет что-то иное, тогда считать иное. Если разделять исходную строку и получать список, в котором нужно еще иметь и символ '\n', тогда ' '...'.splitlines(keepends=True).  Если не устраивает слишком большой получаемый список(памяти много отъедается?), тогда встроить код на "с" и исп. символьный массив и указатели. Думаю, вы сами все это знаете. Но тогда я так и не понял, в чем суть вопроса.

Comment: О *"здесь распознаются только символы \n"*: по умолчанию текстовые потоки (`open()`) в Питоне используют "universal newline mode" это значит, что распознаются \r \n \r\n как окончания строк и возвращается только \n. То есть обычно после чтения только \n остаются в строке, поэтому `wc_line_count = lambda s: s.count('\n')` или ваше определение: `line_count = lambda s: len(s) and s.count('\n') + (not s.endswith('\n'))` работает часто на практике.

Comment: `str.splitlines()` больше символов в качестве новой строки считает, к примеру: \f, \v. Если хочется это поведение, то можно регулярные выражения использовать (хотя было бы удобно, если count принимал бы tuple нескольких строк, как это endswith() делает, тогда можно было бы передать вместо \n, набор символов, которые мы хотим рассматривать новыми строками): `splitlines_line_count = lambda s: sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r"\n|\f|\v|...", s))`

Comment: вариаций на тему может быть много, не ясно что делать с вопросами автора 1) "этом случае создаётся временный список, который может быть довольно большим" и  2)"Насколько я понимаю, в стандартной библиотеке Python нет функции, объединяющей достоинства обоих методов", кроме того, механизм regexp и так сам по себе медлителен и его стараются избегать в обработке больших блоков данных(экспон. рост по мере увеличения сложности шаблона обработки, если быть точным). А у автора и так проблема больших списков, как я понял.