# Поиск подстроки в Python3

Tags: python-3.x, строки, сортировка

И так вот мой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
name = "Result_0.txt"
print("Выбран :", name)
f = open(name, 'r')
open("output"+name, 'tw', encoding='utf-8')
newf = open("output"+name,'w')
i = 0;
for line in open(name):
    i += 1
    i += len(line)
print("Всего строк:", i)
line = f.readlines()
count = 0;
trash = 0;
while count < i:
    if '@mai.ru' in line[count]:
        newf.write(line[count])
    count += 1
```

Но он к сожалению не работает

```
i86@i86 dbsorter]$ ./dbsorter.py
Выбран : Result_0.txt
Всего строк: 12230491
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dbsorter.py", line 18, in <module>
    if '@mai.ru' in line[count]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Помогите отладить код

Comment: Вы знаете что у Вас `i` не правильно считается? И что строчка `Всего строк: 12230491` не означает количество строк в файле?

Comment: i не правильно считает? А как сделать чтоб правильно считала?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вывести количество строк в файле](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550742/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в этом цикле:

```
for line in open(name):
    i += 1
    i += len(line)
```

в переменную i записываете количество строк + количество символов в файле.
Конечно вы выйдете за границы списка строк, ведь i намного больше len(line)

Нужно оставить так:

```
for line in open(name):
    i += 1
```

Ещё не забывайте после работы с файлами закрыть их:

```
f.close()
newf.close()
```

Comment: А вместо цикла, можно так `i = len(list(open(name)))` ?

Comment: а если в этом примете то так: `i = len(list(f))` ?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогли

Comment: Можно для небольших файлов. Очень объёмный текст лучше обрабатывать в цикле построчно.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Result_0.txt"
word = '@mai.ru'
print("Выбран :", name)

with open(name) as file, open("output_%s" % name, 'w') as out_file:
    lines = list(file)
    print("Всего строк:", len(lines))
    for line in lines:
        if word in line:
            emails = [eml for eml in line.split() if word in eml]
            out_file.write('%s\n' % emails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести строки из заданного файла, которые содержат подстроку, заданную в командной строке (`fgrep` аналог):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Print lines from stdin containing *word*.

Usage: fgrep.py <word> 
"""
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)

word = sys.argv[1]
for line in sys.stdin:
    if word in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Пример:

```
$ fgrep.py '@mai.ru' < input.txt > output.txt
```

См. [Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)

Если кодировка файлов отличается от кодировки ввода вывода по умолчанию (вероятно из локали: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`), то можно `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения определить:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 fgrep.py '@mai.ru' < input.txt > output.txt
```