# Числовая сортировка файла по заданной колонке, содержащей число в середине

Tags: bash, сортировка, unix

Есть простой файл: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZVZq6hta

Хочу отсортировать его по параметру `response_time`.

Причём надо учитывать, что время может быть как совсем малым (7), так и большим (11030) (https://pastebin.com/raw/Hu8uFXJA):

```
1 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,507:INFO :pool-8982-thread-30:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==43975&items, response_time=11030, response_code=300 
2 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,628:INFO :pool-8982-thread-77:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==PBD4766&items, response_time=1142, response_code=200 
3 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,651:INFO :pool-8982-thread-67:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==MDC1810C&items, response_time=1166, response_code=200 
4 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,655:INFO :pool-8984-thread-47:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1031086&items, response_time=1005, response_code=200 
5 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,668:INFO :pool-8984-thread-50:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==F1018P&items, response_time=1018, response_code=200 
6 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,677:INFO :pool-8983-thread-86:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==V2581261&items, response_time=1060, response_code=200 
7 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,681:INFO :pool-8982-thread-68:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==202581&items, response_time=1196, response_code=200 
8 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,686:INFO :pool-8984-thread-46:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1563200600&, response_time=1036, response_code=200 
9 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,693:INFO :pool-8983-thread-29:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==8DB355025371, response_time=7, response_code=200
```

`uri` я сократил для краткости, в реальности он может содержать переменное количество символа "=".

Использую:

```
sort -n -t " " -k 8 myfile.txt
```

На выходе получаю тот же самый файл. Почему?

Comment: зачем вы удалили свой же ответ? Что с ним не так?

Comment: Он не работает на втором примере. Это понятно, коротенький пример. Но когда я стал на большом примере смотреть, то у меня получалось, что задержка в районе 2 секунд  было ниже, чем 4 секунд.

Answer (score 5):

наиболее подходящий вариант сортировки — это, конечно, числовая (опция `-n` программы *sort*).

но к приведённым данным она, увы, неприменима: сортируемое поле начинается не с цифр, а с символов, отчего сортировка и не происходит.

наименее «болезненный» (на мой взгляд) вариант «обхода» — это добавить пробел после `response_time=`, и сортировать уже 9-е поле:

```
$ sed 's/ response_time=/& /' файл | sort -nk 9
```

если необходимо, пробел после сортировки можно убрать:

```
$ sed 's/ response_time=/& /' файл | sort -nk 9 | sed 's/\( response_time=\) /\1/'
```

---

ах, да, в комментариях ещё подсказывают, что можно ведь указать и символьное смещение в сортируемом поле:

```
$ sort -nk 8.16 файл
```

Comment: +1 за `sort -nk 8.16`

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант, который я попытался использовать не работает:

```
sort -Vk8 myfile.txt
```

Получилось сделать таким образом, но в этом случае теряются данные о самой строке:

```
grep -Po "response_time=[\d]+" method-wrapped.txt | sort | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Пробуйте `sort -nk8.16 myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
cat IN_FILE | python -c "
import sys
def sort_key(line):
    line = line[line.find('response_time='):].replace('response_time=', '')
    line = line[:line.find(',')]
    return int(line)
print(''.join(sorted(sys.stdin, key=sort_key))" > OUT_FILE
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но понимаешь в чём дело. В таком случае я могу просто выкатить тяжёлую артиллерию в виде Java и написать простенькую консольную тулзу, которая автоматом будет сортировать на базе regex :-)

Comment: Ну java так же просто как питон запустить не выйдет.)

Comment: можно `< IN_FILE` вместо `cat IN_FILE |` подставить. Можно регулярные выражения использовать: `sort_key = lambda line: int(re.search(r"response_time=(\d+)", line).group(1))`

Comment: Выглядит как очень сильное переусложнение :-) можно же все просто средствами sort сделать

Answer (score 0):

Для более сложных критериев, когда `sort -nk 8.16 файл` не работает  или не  доступен, можно perl попробовать, чтобы произвольный regex применить:

```
$ perl -e 'print map  { $_->[0] } 
                 sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
                 map  { [$_, /response_time=(\d+)/] } <>' файл
```

Это так называемая сортировка с помощью [преобразования Шварца (1994)](http://perltricks.com/article/the-history-of-the-schwartzian-transform/):

1. Регулярное выражение `/response_time=(\d+)/` находит ключ, по которому сортировка происходит
2. `$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]` выражение сравнивает ключи как числа
3. `$_->[0]` достаёт входные строки.

Код предполагает, что символ новой строки присутствует и на последней строчке, [по аналогии с `wc -l`, `cat *.txt`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550931/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Опция -n у вас не работала, т.к. в поле не только цифры.
Стоит исключить из сортировки буквы, и вуаля:

```
cat tst |sort -k8.15,9 -n -t' '                                                                                                                 
9 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,693:INFO :pool-8983-thread-29:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==8DB355025371, response_time=7, response_code=200
4 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,655:INFO :pool-8984-thread-47:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1031086&items, response_time=1005, response_code=200
5 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,668:INFO :pool-8984-thread-50:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==F1018P&items, response_time=1018, response_code=200
8 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,686:INFO :pool-8984-thread-46:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==1563200600&, response_time=1036, response_code=200
6 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,677:INFO :pool-8983-thread-86:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==V2581261&items, response_time=1060, response_code=200
2 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,628:INFO :pool-8982-thread-77:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==PBD4766&items, response_time=1142, response_code=200
3 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,651:INFO :pool-8982-thread-67:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==MDC1810C&items, response_time=1166, response_code=200
7 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,681:INFO :pool-8982-thread-68:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==202581&items, response_time=1196, response_code=200
1 console-2017_09_17.log:2017-09-17 00:04:02,507:INFO :pool-8982-thread-30:r.a.u.j.PerfRequestInterceptor - method=GET, uri==43975&items, response_time=11030, response_code=300
```

Упс, не увидел конец самого первого ответа :-(