# Пронумеровать строки в файле

Tags: python, строки, текст

Есть текстовый файл, в котором однотипные строки без нумерации.
Как нумеровать строки последовательно?

Пробую так, выдаёт ошибку (пример нашёл в интернете):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

lines = 0
file = f.open ("/home/**/**/FiltredInterface.txt") 
    for line in file:
        lines +=1
        print (line)
```

Comment: 1. Какую именно ошибку? 2. Этот код (когда его исправить) не будет нумеровать строки, а просто напечатет числа от 1 до N, где N - количество строк.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, вы хотите пронумеровать строки и записать нумерованные строки в файл? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Да, нужно пронумеровать стровки в файле и иметь на выходе в файле номер строки + сама строка.

ошибка : "for line in file:       IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: " IndentationError: unexpected indent" - вбивайте ошибку в гугл и смотрите, что она означает.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вывести количество строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550742/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы по месту файл изменить, добавив номер строки к каждой строке (версия `nl` утилиты, которая по месту изменения выполняет):

```
import fileinput
import os

def number_lines(filename, start=1):
    """Number lines in the *filename* inplace counting from *start*."""
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for n, line in enumerate(file, start=start):
            print(n, line, end='')
    os.unlink(filename + '.bak') # remove backup on success
```

Пример:

```
number_lines("/home/user/path/to/FiltredInterface.txt")
```

Comment: Сработало , спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 3):

Если в итоге необходимо получить файл с аналогичным содержанием и пронумерованными строками можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as read_object, open('output.txt', 'w') as write_object:
    for idx, line in enumerate(read_object, start=1):
        write_object.write('{} {}'. format(idx, line))
```

Comment: стирает файл полностью, к сожалению

Comment: @Oleksandr Shulha Я редактировал код, возможно вы воспользовались ошибочным вариантом, попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: всё верно , файл output.txt остаётся пустым (если имел какое-то содержание - стирает) .

Comment: @Oleksandr Shulha А в файле, путь до которого вы указываете вместо 'input.txt',  есть содержимое?

Comment: Да, конечно. Я всё проверил изначально.

Answer (score 2):

Так же эту задачу можно решить при помощи контекстного менеджера  разработанного Мартином Питерсом для перезаписи файла на месте ([Easy in-place file rewriting](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2013/11/26/inplace-file-rewriting/)).

Пример из статьи:

```
import csv

with inplace(csvfilename, 'r', newline='') as (infh, outfh):
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)

    for row in reader:
        row += ['new', 'columns']
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в лишнем отступе для цикла и том, что вы забыли вывести переменную счетчик.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

lines = 0
file = open("./text.txt")
for line in file:
    lines +=1
    print (lines, line)
```