# Как методом .format добавить в начало каждой строки комментарий с номером этой строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю лабораторную работу, по условию задачи я должен взять файл .py и вставить в начало каждой строки '#i', где i будет номером этой строки.
Для этого я хочу применить метод .format.

Как правильно составить такую команду? Пробовал через '+' и через '%' и через ',' - везде ошибка: UnsupportedOperation: not readable

```
temp = []
file = open('example.py', 'r')
for line in file.read().split('\n'):
    temp.append(line)

file.close()

file1 = open('example.py', 'w')
i = 1
for line in file1:
    file1.write('#%i'%i.format(line.strip())+ '\n') #строка с ошибкой
    i = i+1

file1.close()
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Пронумеровать строки в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775086/23044)

Comment: `UnsupportedOperation: not readable` вызван `'w'` режимом и `for line in file1` строкой. Если это не ясно, задайте отдельный вопрос именно о `not readable` ошибке (traceback полный приведите).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлять так:

```
newline = "#{0} {1}".format(i, line)
```

Но код вам все равно придется править. Зачем вам переменная `temp`, если она нигде не используется?

Comment: согласен про temp, ошибся, однако в вашем примере строка добавлялась в никуда.

Comment: Так работает, спасибо за ответ. newline = "#{0} {1} \n".format(i, line)
file1.write(newline)

Comment: Все убрал, оставил только одну строку с форматированием, а то действительно мой код целиком был нерабочий :)

Comment: @jfs Пробел - чтобы лучше читалось, новая строка добавляется в вопросе, скопировал оттуда. Можно не добавлять.

Comment: @jfs действительно, пустая строка появляется в конце, которая еще и тоже нумеруется. Не подскажете, как ее убрать? Ведь если убрать \n запись в файле будет происходить в 1 строку.

Comment: @badordos Убрать `\n`. Одной строки не будет, перевод на новую строку уже есть в самой строчке.

Comment: @badordos: `line` уже содержит новую строку, не нужно добавлять ещё. [Вот полный пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775128/23044), замените `print(n, line, end='')` на `print(f"#{n} {line}", end='')`, чтобы с помощью `''.format` нумерованные комментарии выставить.

Comment: @Эникейщик если убрать \n - все будет в одну строку.

Comment: Пустая строка появляется, когда я считываю и разделяю файл на строки, используя разделитель по \n, так что изменение записи тут не поможет, похоже

Comment: Используйте `.readline()` -  автоматически читает построчно.