# Посчитать кол-во строк при копировании в другой файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код для копирования во второй файл, но вот как посчитать кол-во строк в нем я не могу понять, видел вот такую штуку, но не смог ее прикрутить к программе.

```
print sum(1 for _ in f)
```

сам код

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open('t2.txt', 'w+') as output, open('t1.txt', 'r') as input:
    copyfileobj(input, output)
```

Comment: Какие были попытки? В чем именно возникли проблемы? Кстати, не следует использовать ``input`` в качестве имени переменной. Это встроенная функция.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вывести количество строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550742/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть на исходный код [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c743a6ac360cfa1d9de7e6fad98b68fca39367d5/Lib/shutil.py#L76-L82) и добавить к нему подсчёт строк, чтобы не читать исходный файл два раза:

```
def count_lines_and_copyfileobj(
    input_file, output_file, chunk_size=16384, newline="\n"
):
    """Count lines while copying a file."""
    count = 0
    chunk = newline
    for chunk in iter(lambda: input_file.read(chunk_size), type(newline)()):
        count += chunk.count(newline)
        output_file.write(chunk)
    return count + (not chunk.endswith(newline))
```

См. [Вывести количество строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550931/23044).

Пример использования:

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file, \
     open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    number_of_lines = count_lines_and_copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Алгоритм однопроходной, поэтому его можно использовать с pipes (non-seekable files). К примеру, передать `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout` в качестве `input_file`/`output_file`, а затем использовать полученный скрипт в shell pipeline:

```
source_program | count_lines_and_cat | sink
```

Answer (score 0):

Посчитать количество строк в файле можно следующим образом:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines_total = len(file.readlines())
```